# How do I arrange data using XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
My XSL-

    <xsl:template match="Identity" mode="Insureds">
    X    : <xsl:value-of select="X"/>
    Y    : <xsl:value-of select="Y"/>
    </xsl:template>

My XML-

    <A identity="1">
      <X>P</X>
      <Y>R</Y>
    </A>
    <A identity="2">
      <X>Q</X>
      <Y>R</Y>
    </A>
```

Here only 2 loop is possible and value of 'Y' if present it will be same like 'R' in both.

Hi , I need to print data using xsl. Problem is here if there are two loops 
it print like

```
X : P
Y : R
X : Q
Y : R
```

But I need like below

```
X : P
    Q
Y : R
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a grouping problem you can solve in XSLT 2 or 3 (as supported in Java by Saxon 9) using

```
  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="A/*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key() || ' : '"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by=".">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BJ/1

Comment: Thanks for your ans @Martin , could you please provide me this solution using if test=position condition in between xsl . Thanks.